# git does not do rebase

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I want to rebase my feature branch into dev branch, so I do

```
git checkout feature
git rebase dev
```

then I get

```
Current branch feature is up to date
```

thats already strange, shouldn't it update the dev and not the feature?

further

```
git checkout dev
git log
```

shows that there is no new commits from the feature added. What am I doing wrong?

and

Comment: `git rebase` changes the current branch, no the branch you want to rebase on.

Comment: I guess probably what you want to do is `git checkout feature`, `git rebase dev`, `git checkout dev`, and `git merge feature`. This first updates feature's start point to the tip of dev, and then merges the commits made in feature into dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `dev` is your primary branch.

If you initial branched `feature` off of `dev` (or another branch that was at the same commit point as dev HEAD) and no changes have been commited to `dev`  since that branching, when inside `feature`  (as you are by doing the checkout) if you rebase to `dev`, nothing should happen.  `HEAD`commit of `dev` is already `feature`'s base commit.

If commits had been made to `dev`, then the rebase would have rebased feature to the new `dev` `HEAD`.

You don't want to rebase `dev`, you rebase your `feature` branch if needed (if `dev` having changed while working on your feature), then merge the rebased feature branch back into `dev`.

Here's my flow assuming dev is my primary branch:

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b feature
```

Now I'm in my feature branch.  I Made some changes to feature branch commit them, maybe dev has changed in meantime.  Still on feature branch, so changing back to dev to look for any changes

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
```

So changes happened on dev, so I want to rebase my feature branch

```
git checkout feature
git rebase dev
```

Now I'm ready to merge my feature branch back into dev

```
git checkout dev
git merge --squash feature
```

Squash is optional, but it condenses changes in the feature branch into a single commit on merging back to dev.

Finally, push the new dev back up for others to enjoy

```
git push origin dev
```

Comment: thanks, correct I didnt have changes in the dev branch, so simple merge helped out